# How to update Datagridview after inserting Data

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datagridview

I can insert my data into MySql database, but on C# application I also want that the datagridview updates after pressing the button but I don't know how. It only refreshes in the datagridview after closing the C# application and opening again.

```
private void btnEintrag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Netzwerk IP-Adresse ermitteln  
    IPHostEntry Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    string IPAddress = Host.AddressList[1].ToString();

    string datasource = IPAddress;
    string database = "datenbank";
    string port = "xxx";
    string UID = "xxxx";
    string pw = "xxx";

    string myConnection;
    myConnection = string.Format("datasource=" + datasource + ";" + "Database=" + database + ";" + "port=" + port + ";" + "UID=" + UID + ";" + "password=" + pw);
    string VName, NName, Zusatztext;
    VName = txtVName.Text;
    NName = txtNName.Text;
    Zusatztext = txtZusatz.Text;

    Eintrag.CreateEntry(myConnection, VName, NName, Zusatztext); //Creates an Entry in the Table
}

private void BindGrid() //with this function I can see the data in datagridview
{
     IPHostEntry Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
     string IPAddress = Host.AddressList[1].ToString();
     MessageBox.Show(IPAddress);

     string datasource = IPAddress;
     string database = "datenbank";
     string port = "3306";
     string UID = "outside";
     string pw = "mysql";

     string myConnection;
     myConnection = string.Format("datasource=" + datasource + ";" + "Database=" + database + ";" + "port=" + port + ";" + "UID=" + UID + ";" + "password=" + pw);

     using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
     {
         using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Formular", con))
         {
              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

              using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
              {
                  using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                  {
                      sda.Fill(dt);
                      dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
}

private void UpdateDataGridView()
{
      ?????? I don't know 
}
```

Comment: Is the database updated from some other application? You can add a Refresh button and call BindGrid() when it's clicked.

Comment: thanks u are right i don´t know how i couldnt see that. Thanks for ur answer!

Comment: Do u also know how i can autoresize my Datagridview? im searching in the Internet right know but i cant find a solution for my problem

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by autoresize, if you want it to change its size when the window is resized, try to set its Dock property to Fill.

Comment: I agree with @NadiaChibrikova: please add more specifics to your question and narrow it down to the boundaries of your original title. Best regards,